# jQuery animate reset relative position

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery animation that is animating a relativley positioned div across the screen using the left value.

My issue is that I want the div to jump back to the start after it has finished.  I have been unable to do this and I assume its to do with the realative positioning.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you have to give more details, can you post something of the code or create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers, depending on what you're trying to do (I'm not exactly sure, so just read my answers).

### Animate to right and then to left

If you wish to first animate the element and when this animation finishes, fire up another one that animates to the left, then do the following.

```
$("#el").animate({left: "500px"}, 300, function() {
  $("#el").animate({left: "0px"});
}
```

Just make sure that the `#el` element has `position: relative; left: something;` set in CSS.

### Animate element to the left when a limit is reached

If you wish to continuosly move the element right and then when a specified limit is reached (for example 500px), animate it to the left.

```
var $el = $("#el");
$("#el").click(function() {
  var current_left = $el.css("left");
  $el.animate({left: (current_left + 100) + "px"}, 300);
  if (current_left >= 500)
    $el.stop().animate({left: "0px"}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the width instead of left position and in the callback function of the animation, clone it then remove it.

Lets say you are using images wrapped with links:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="container"> <a href="#"><img src"1.jpg" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src"2.jpg" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src"3.jpg" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src"4.jpg" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #wrap {
       position:relative;
       margin: 9px 0px 0px 6px;
       overflow:hidden;
       height: 200px;
       width: 237px;
   }
   #container {
       position:absolute;
       width: 9999px;
       height:200px;
   }
   #container img {
       display:inline-block;
       width: 237px;
       height:200px;
       border: 1px solid #000;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       /* Firefox, other Gecko */
       box-sizing: border-box;
       /* Opera/IE 8+ */
   }
```

JQUERY/JS:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $container = $('#container');
    $container.children().first('a').animate({
        "width": "0px"
    }, 500, "linear", function () {
        $container.children().first('a').clone().appendTo($container).css("width", "237px");
        $container.children().first('a').remove();
    });
}, 1000);
```

With a little tweaking to your needs you should be able to make this work in any situation where a quick slider is needed. Thanks ahead for the check up! #frontEnd4Life #death2Tables

Here is a fiddle so you can see the action: http://jsfiddle.net/F8g2p/10/